# Android, Parsing JSON object

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, arrays

When i call server its response is based of json object. Actually, I know how to parse JSON object but this response is strange for me. Server response is:

```
{"body":"Not Available!","clazz":"SoccerMatchPreview","id":{"inc":-2024241794,"machine":415106952,"new":false,"time":1337861978000,"timeSecond":1337861978},"publishedDate":"2012-06-08 17:00:00 +0100","refKey":"SoccerMatchPreview_4fb897be18be8b87f9117595","title":"Poland vs Greece"}
```

Those Information that I need are body, publishedDate, refKey and title. The code that i have written based of JSON object is this:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray contestantObjects = jObject.getJSONArray("id");
                    for(int i=0; i<contestantObjects.length(); i++) {
                        mPreview.setBody(contestantObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("body").toString());
                        mPreview.setPublishedDate(contestantObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("publishedDate").toString());
                        mPreview.setRefKey(contestantObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("refKey").toString());
                        mPreview.setTitle(contestantObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("title").toString());
                    }
```

But because it doesn't have "[]" I think it's not JSON object. therefore, I wrote another code based JSON array.

```
JSONArray contestantObjects = new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i=0; i<contestantObjects.length(); i++) {
                        mPreview.setBody(contestantObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("body").toString());
                        mPreview.setPublishedDate(contestantObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("publishedDate").toString());
                        mPreview.setRefKey(contestantObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("refKey").toString());
                        mPreview.setTitle(contestantObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("title").toString());
                    }
```

but result is same and Logcat shows:

> Value {"id":{"timeSecond":1337861978,"time":1337861978000,"new":false,"machine":415106952,"inc":-2024241794},"body":"Not Available!","title":"Poland vs Greece","publishedDate":"2012-06-08 17:00:00 +0100","clazz":"SoccerMatchPreview","refKey":"SoccerMatchPreview_4fb897be18be8b87f9117595"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JSONArray contestantObjects = jObject.getJSONArray("id");
```

Your error is here, `id` is itself a complex object, not an array.

```
"id":{"inc":-2024241794,"machine":415106952,"new":false,"time":1337861978000,"timeSecond":1337861978}
```

Therefore, after getting the `id` JSON object, you should be able to get the individual attributes, e.g. `inc`, `machine`, `new`, `time`, and `timeSecond`.

```
JSONObject idObject = ...getJSONObject("id");
String machine = idObject.get("machine");
```

A JSON array data structure would have looked like this: `[]` signifies an array.

For example, `"Animals":["Pig", "Cat", "Dog"]`.

In another example, it can also be an Array of complex objects, `"Animals":[{"name":"AAA", "blood":"A"}, {"name":"BBB", "blood":"B"}]`.

**EDIT: Here is a good JSON visualizer i would recommend.**

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

[image]

Comment: Thanks dear Chin, based on what you mentioned i found that "id" is wrong key because i don't need its items. How to get body, publishedDate, refKey and title? Based of what, should i have to parse "response" string?

Comment: To get publishedDate, refKey, and title, you would only need JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response); String publishedDate = jObject.get("publishedDate"); and so on.

Comment: This part, i would strongly recommend that you look into a good JSON library, GSON from Google seems to be a good one. Here is a short tutorial: http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/

Comment: Thanks Chin i could parse it.