# How to pass json array using get method in retrofit android

Tags: android, retrofit

I am new to retrofit,and not having much idea how to pass this json using retrofit and show in my app.Below is my json, MainActivity and model class.But know it is throwing an exception "Except begin_object but found begin_array".Please help me.

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt",
        "body": "sdfdsf"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "jhmjk"
      }]
```

MainActivity.java

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        ApiInterface apiService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        // ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ModelClass> call = apiService.getLogin();
        // Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.loginWithCredentials(new LoginRequest(email_enter, md5pass));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ModelClass> call, Response<ModelClass> response) {
                Log.i("REGISTRATION --->", "Registered" + response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ModelClass> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("REGISTRATION --->", "Throwable" + t.toString());
                // Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                // startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

ModelClass.java

```
public class ModelClass {
    class Model{
        public List<ObjectModel> getObjectmodel() {
            return objectmodel;
        }

        public void setObjectmodel(List<ObjectModel> objectmodel) {
            this.objectmodel = objectmodel;
        }

        List<ObjectModel> objectmodel;
    }

    class ObjectModel{
        String userId;
        String id;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(String userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getBody() {
            return body;
        }

        public void setBody(String body) {
            this.body = body;
        }

        String title;
        String body;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass JSON array inside body in retrofit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543318/how-to-pass-json-array-inside-body-in-retrofit)

Comment: Can u please see this link,having json,how to pass that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386604/login-using-retrofit-in-android-having-json-data-at-server

Comment: I would suggest to pass the JSON data in the body as a POST request

Answer (score 2):

Create custom model and pass same model in retrofit api.

```
class Model{
   List<ObjectModel> objectmodel;
 }

class ObjectModel{
   String userId;
   String id;
   String title;
   String body;
}
```

Bind value and pass Model object in your retrofit interface.

Or

```
@GET("json")
Call<JsonObject> youmethode(@Query("key") String value);
```

Hope this is helpful. thanks

Comment: How to pass this after @Get()

Comment: do you know how to pass parameter in retrofit?

Comment: @GET("json")
    Call<JsonObject> getDistance(@Query("origins") String origins, @Query("destinations") String destinations, @Query("key") String key);

Otherwise you can direct pass json object in retrofit interface

Comment: I am just having url which provides me data.I don't need to give anything.So for that how to pass parameter

Comment: if you don't need to give anything then why you want to pass parameter

Comment: Can u please see this link,having json,how to pass that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386604/login-using-retrofit-in-android-having-json-data-at-server

Answer (score 0):

To pass json request, you have to use post method.

Comment: Can u please see this link,having json,how to pass that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386604/login-using-retrofit-in-android-having-json-data-at-server